# Bluetooth Serial Errors

Tags: ros, arduino, serial, bluetooth, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

1.
I am trying to run an Arduino ROS node connected with a bluetooth serial link. I can get it connected, (with rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/rfcomm0)
but it won't stay connected for very long. I get the following error (repeatedly):

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1350185780.476810] bad callback: <bound method Subscriber.callback of <rosserial_python.SerialClient.Subscriber instance at 0xa2b65cc>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py", line 581, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 121, in callback
self.parent.send(self.id, data_buffer.getvalue())
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 473, in send
self.port.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 485, in write
raise SerialException('write failed: %s' % (v,))
SerialException: write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Has anyone seen this before and knows what to do about it?

2.
Also, does any one know what this error means? I get it as I run my program, but I can receive messages from my Arduino regardless of if its showing...

[INFO] [WallTime: 1350185758.107044] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45797/bluetooth-serial-errors/) by [sgwhack](https://answers.ros.org/users/2844/sgwhack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Errno 5] usually indicates that the port read/write has failed because the port was no longer available, perhaps your Bluetooth link if dropping out?

As for question #2, it means that part of a packet was corrupted/lost causing the whole packet to be dropped (over a noisy wireless link this is somewhat expected).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0